# Obtaining x y z positions using linear and angular velocities data

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-velocity

I need to obtain position of a vehicle by using linear and angular velocities data in 3 Dimensions.

I'm trying to do this in Simulink but I don't know what should I do to get  positions?

Please help and say where can I find info about this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here.  Maybe it would be useful if you could provide an example.

Comment: I attached simulink model, may be it helps. I want to get orientation angles by using angular velocities. Then another model to get x y z positions by using linear velocities.

Comment: Sorry I meant an examples of the equations you want to simulate, and some context as to the boundary conditions etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is one of the classic navigation problems.

The good news: There's an *enormous* corpus of text on the topic

The bad news: People literally make their careers solving these sorts of problems.

One thing which is known is that you can't separate the angular calculations from the linear ones.  You need the angles to figure out the linear terms because the axes for the linear sensor rotate with the object (if you're somehow measuring x y z velocities from off-board, then the equations are simpler).

Of course, there's *tons* of issues with drift and bias and all sorts of effects like that.  One common tool for resolving those issues is a Kalman Filter, which you might want to look into.

In general, you will find real systems try to integrate information from as many sources as possible to resolve drift effects.  For example, many inertial units will then fuse that data with GPS information to correct long term drift while still being able to use the incredible precision of the inertial measurements on the shorter timescales.